# Language c slowing down loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I have for loop which makes falling effect in matrix. I am generating numbers in the first row of matrix and the fall.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void hra(){
    .....
    do {
        for(int i = V; i > 0; i--) { 
            for(int j = 0; j < S; j++) {
            mat1[i][j] = mat1[i - 1][j];
            }
        }....}
     }
```

But now its too quick. When i use Sleep() it will slow down everything (user input etc..)
Is there a way to slow down only this loop (and gradually make it quicker)?

//
I am sorry I should have mentioned that the user sees the falling numbers and have to interact with them (the numbers fall at the bottom of the matrix where they get stored or they get erased by user). So I want them to "fall" slowly so the user can see them and decide which ones he want or dont. And V is 10 and S 4.

Comment: What do you mean too quick? Wouldn't you want it to be as fast as possible?

Comment: you should know that, **If you are using Windows, Sleep takes time in milliseconds.** and **If you are using Linux, sleep takes time in seconds.**

Comment: why does it matter what season it is?

Comment: The seems like an X-Y question.  If in some sense it is desirable for the code to run slower then that can only be for the purpose of some kind of UI effect, which goes unmentioned.  How about asking about *that*, the real problem?

Comment: What are the values for `v` and `s`

Comment: If `mat1[][]` is of size `mat1[V][S]`, then code is accessing outside its range with `for(int i = V; i > 0; i--) {  ... mat1[i][j]` leading to undefined behavior.  Post the definition of `mat1[][]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is multi-threading. Have the main thread do the calculations, have another thread do the graphics and a third thread handle to user input.

Answer (score 0):

`usleep()` takes a time in microseconds as parameter, you could put a variable as value and then decrement it. Per example if you want to slow down this for:

`for(int i = V; i > 0; i--)`

you could add:

`usleep(x * i);`

in it. (Where x is whatever you want.) Feel free to use any equation you want to choose the way it will slow down.